# Fatest string comparison using eloquent

Tags: excel, laravel, laravel-5.8, maatwebsite-excel

I'm importing data using [Maatwebsite](https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel) from an excel file and before creating a new row in my model I check if the register already exists to avoid duplicates. But this takes too long.

In my `ProductImport.php`:

```
public function model(array $row)
{
    
    $exists = Product::
        where('product_description', $row["product_description"])
        ->where('product_code', $row["product_code"])
        ->first();
    
    if($exists ){
        return null;
    }

    ++$this->rows;
    
    // Autoincrement id
    return new Product([
        "product_description" => $row["art_descripcion"],
        "product_code" => $row["cui"],
        "id_user" => $this->id_user,
        ...
    ]);
}

public function chunkSize(): int
{
    return 1000;
}
```

As you see, I'm also using chunkSize, because there are 5000 rows per excel.

**The problem:**

The size of the `product_description` varies between 800 to 900 characters (varchar[1000]) and it makes the query (`where()`) very slow per iteration within the `foreach`.

Is there a better way to handle this? Maybe using `updateOrCreate` instead of searching first and then creating? Because I think it will be the same approach.

So the main problem is how do I compare those 800 - 900 size string quicker? Because this search is taking a lot of time to execute:

```
 $exists = Product::
        where('product_description', $row["product_description"])
        ->where('product_code', $row["product_code"])
        ->first();
```

Comment: Well the naïve approach would be to create indexes (or even a composite index), however I must ask, is there a scenario where you'd add two products with different descriptions but with the same product code?

Comment: Yes. Because there are products that can have the same code but different description. Example: [code: p-12, description: red pencil], [code:p-12, description: blue pencil ], etc.

Comment: It might be helpful to construct the query that is being done here it would be something like `SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_description = ? and product_code = ?` then do an EXPLAIN on that query. Your end goal would be to have indexes to allow fast lookups, take a look at [indexes](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#indexes) to find one that works for you. It might take some trial and error

Comment: I think to something like that : create a new field where you stock the hash value of the product_description, and you compare those hashed strings...

Comment: I'm not using migrations but I'll check that documentation about indexes!

Comment: Migrations are just convenience for db operations and specifically the index commands in migrations do things like e.g. `CREATE INDEX`